# How to play embedded youtube video in webview android with a button

Tags: android, webview, youtube

In android code with layout file I have a button, by clicking on that button I want to play YouTube video in the web-view. Any Idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your activity try adding this

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
   WebView wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewYoutube);
   wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   wv.loadUrl("your youtube video URL"); 
}
```